# Why have I stopped getting access to mail and calendar and some Microsoft application after I took ownership of WindowsApps folder?

Tags: windows, permissions, windows-11, calendar, ownership

After I took ownership of WindowsApps folder, I stopped getting access to mail and calendar applications and some other Microsoft application.

Why is that? How can I undo what I just did?

Comment: Why would you try to take ownership of a very secure folder?  See if you can undo the permissions.  It may be difficult to repair if not.

Comment: "Why is that?" - I am shocked any UWP application works for you.  You are not supposed to take ownership of the WindowsApps folder. You must perform a fresh Windows (not a repair install) to reverse your actions.

Comment: I had iCloud error that there is not enough permission for it to function.

Comment: It's called "security". Many applications, in both Windows and Linux, will fail to run if they discover the permissions placed on their executable files have been tampered with.

Answer (score 1):

Mucking with secure permissions can significant damage to internal registry entries or to User Profiles.

**(1)** Try a Windows 10 Repair install (11 is similar).

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.

**(2)** If that fails (in this case I think it might), the damage is more serious.

SO then back up everything and reset Windows back to original and restore your apps and data.